# Suddenly getting different User IDs from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read that Facebook is now issuing User IDs on a per-app basis. On our platform, we haven't changed the way we interact through Facebook - still using same API endpoints and SDKs. However, we've suddenly started seeing an issue where user IDs are changing without notice. So before we were getting the real User ID, and now we're getting the app-specific User ID.

Can someone confirm Facebook is indeed going through all of its APIs and changing the ID being returned? This is problematic since it's breaking logins for some of our users.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but policies and changes to Facebook API. Submit a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: What do you mean with ids changing? In what API call does it change?

Comment: @WizKid if we do a graph request to `/me` we were originally getting a "short" ID that looked like `592388`. Now if we do the same request the ID being returned looks like `1004098828487` for the same user. To prove it, we visited the Facebook URL for each ID (like `facebook.com/592388` and `/1004098828487`) and it was the same profile.

Comment: The id is always the same after the user logs in the first time. Before the user logs in the first time it may be different.

Comment: @WizKid that's what I expected as well, but we have a cluster of user IDs that have logged in previously with our App ID which are showing that behavior. Are you saying they would have needed to delete the app and re-connected?

Comment: If logged in and the id changed after that file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs